# onchange select get value and do query then display result on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Guys I have a problem which I know it's possible to do but not sure how to do it. Any help is much appreciated.

CODE:

```
<select id='bldg'>
    <option value='1'>BLDG1</option>
    <option value='2'>BLDG2</option>
</select>
```

once the user click on BLGD1 the system will run a query getting all rooms of BLDG1 and display the query on a select input too

Result will look like this if user click on BLDG1

```
<select id='room'>
    <option value='101'>Room 101 - BLDG1</option>
    <option value='102'>Room 102 - BLDG1</option>
</select>
```

and then once the user click BLDG2, all the rooms will display on ROOM.
Question: How to display result query on  after users choose/change a building number from 
other info: Codeigniter HMVC; JQUERY

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Anyway, you'd use jQuery to attach a change event handler to the first select. In the handler you'd make an Ajax call to a PHP page that does the database lookup and returns the results. In the Ajax success callback you'd update the second select element's options. (I'm not going to write the code for you from scratch, not when there are lots of examples of this same thing already online.)

Comment: Actually I was able to do this already with static content and I used Jquery but my main question is how to do this if the content is in the database.

Comment: scenario: user choose BLDG1 then all rooms that has flag of BLDG1 will show on a select input without refreshing/reloading the page.

scenario2: user select BLDG2 then the room input will change with a new result from the database that has a flag of BLDG2.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`onchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange). Here's a good jQuery-free solution:

```
//  Grab the element
var sel = document.querySelector('#bldg');
//  Store updated values
var updatedVals = [ "Room 101 - BLDG1", "Room 102 - BLDG2" ];

//  Sets an onchange event function
//  Alternative: sel.addEventListener('onchange', fn() { ... })
sel.onchange = function() {
  //  this.children returns a DOMNodeList, calling slice converts it to a proper array
  var options = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children, 0);
  //  Map/Loop over the array
  options.map(function(option, i){
  //  Change innerHTML of each option to the corresponding updated value
    option.innerHTML = updatedVals[i];
  });
}
```

Check it out on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze1hb7xq/).

Comment: thanks for the answer.
unfortunately, once the bldg ID is change then the room will display or update the content, depending on what the user choose.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing some async stuff when you say "run a query" - put in inside the `onchange` event and it will occur each time the `select` changes

Comment: yes, yes.  if select input change it will do another query and update the content of room